# Deserialize Serialized Object after Refactoring

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String someName;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.someName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.someName;
    }
}
```

I serialize many objects of this class, and save them to disk.  Later, I realize that it would be beneficial to abstract this structure out to an abstract class, leaving me with the following two classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String someName;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.someName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.someName;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize the files from earlier?  Attempting to do so in my tests does not cause an error, but does result in the properties being `null`.

Comment: can you share some of your deserialization code? Aae you casting it like (Foo)objectInputStream.readObject(); ?

Comment: The property has moved classes so it is a different property.  A simple work around is to use version number for your DTOs either in the package or the class name.  This way you can read any version of the class you have had, and can convert it to a new version.

Comment: @FlavorScape Correct.  I'm not overly familiar with serialization code, and what we have in our codebase is a bit more convoluted, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hmm, so in this scenario I would need to leave the Foo class intact as it originally was, and either create a new class NewFoo or add it in a different package if I want to have the refactoring?  Is there no way to "trick" Java's serialization facilities?

Comment: @tredontho There is a trick, you can create your own readObject() and decode the stream for backward compatibility.  Have a look at how this method is used in key classes in `java.lang` and `java.util`  The downside is you will need to understand much more about how Java serialization really works. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah, I wrote a custom readObject method that just pulls the field by name and then sets it via the abstract class's method.  I'm assuming that if I don't write a writeObject method to match, then deserializing will fail since the properties on the newly written object would exist at the superclass level, but this will be trying to deserialize from this class itself?  Either way, I think this may result in more work than the refactoring is worth.  Might just have to enact a "going forward" policy here ;)